# File name and object name correspondence in Scala

Tags: scala

In Scala, singleton object name and file name can be different.

But why it is recommended to have the same file name as object name?

```
    object TryScala
    {
      def main(args: Array[String]) =
      {
        print("hey")
       }
    }
```

I tried changing the object name, it still runs.

Comment: AFAIK for compiler it doesn't matter. But for people working with your code it make things more discoverable.

Answer (score 2):

This is simply a Scala coding style [convention](https://docs.scala-lang.org/style/files.html) to help identify a single logical compilation unit. Note that does not mean there should be just a single entity inside the file, instead, the entities should be logically related. For example, ADT constructors, extension methods, companion objects could all be placed in a single file. Here are few examples form official Scala repo

Option.scala

```
object Option
sealed abstract class Option
final case class Some[+A](value: A) extends Option[A]
case object None extends Option[Nothing]
```

Numeric.scala

```
object Numeric
trait Numeric[T] extends Ordering[T]
```

Map.scala

```
trait Map[K, +V]
trait MapOps
object MapOps
object Map
```